# Can't solve Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, entity-framework

I have a web ASP.NET site that it working fine with WCF services. Now, I have a class Library for Telerik Reports that also needs to call these same web services. I keep getting the error Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'. when I try to add a Service Reference to the web service. I have searched the topic and done everything people pointed out. In the project that implement the web services and the site, the config has:

```
compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
          <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
          <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />

          <add assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
          <add assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
          <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
        </buildProviders>
```

And in the class library config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
    </buildProviders>
```

All of the answers I've read say to add the following but it still does not work:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

Comment: do you have a reference to valid `System.Data.Entity.Design` library? should be located in System.Data.Entity.Design.dll. Where is your EDMX file located?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error in visual studio 2015....

> Could not load type
>   System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider

I  solve the problem by adding the line:

```
<assemblies>
....
 <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
....    
</assemblies>
```

in main **Web.config** file and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

This is the layout of this error making assembly:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            <add
                assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,
                PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation> 
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```